# how to create api's? my api doesnt get called

Tags: node.js, api, express

i created an express project using express-generator. here's my project structure

**project structure**

[image]

users.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
router.get("/abc", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ connect: "success" });
});
module.exports = router;
```

So when i try to open it on localhost:3000/abc, i dont get anything at all.
it says not found 404

here's my app.js

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");

var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
var user = router("./controller/user");

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/abc", user);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  //next(createError(404));
  res.status(404).send("sorry cant find it");
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: provide complete path `users.js` like `./routes/users.js` and also provide code of `app.js` where you use using `users.js`

Comment: try to brows localhost:3000/users/abc

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: You can brows localhost:3000/abc/abc  as you define `/abc` twice

Comment: Well yes it indeed was the error i made. I forgot about it

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

app.get('/abc', function(req, res) {
 res.json({ connect: "success" });
});

module.exports = app;
```

you need to export `app` at the end and you can use `app.get` instead.

**Or**

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/abc", (req, res) => {
    res.json({connect: "success"});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: i have done that, i just missed that here. I have updated the question. But it still doesnt work

Comment: can you post your app.js ?

Comment: @Anita your approach is correct but your url is incorrect. you need to use your url like localhost:3000/users/abc

Answer (score 0):

You must `module.exports` router in `users.js`

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/abc", (req, res) => {
    res.json({connect: "success"});
});

module.exports = router;
```